# How do I get the full timezone name from a Datetime without importing Time?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to display my full time zone along with my current local time.

```
print "Your current time is {0} {1} ".format(datetime.datetime.now().time(), time.tzname[0])
```

And the result would look something like:

```
Your current time is 08:35:45.328000 Pacific Standard Time
```

The problem is I have to import the Time library (sorry if I call it wrong, I'm coming from C#) along with the Datetime library.

```
import datetime
import time
```

I've looked into the `naive` and `aware` states of time, but still can't seem to get the desired result.

Is there a way to get the full timezone name (i.e.: Pacific Standard Time) from Datetime without having to import Time?

Comment: The `time` module doesn't do anything for you here. Are you perhaps looking for the `pytz` third-party module?

Comment: @ShadowRanger It helps me get the timezone name in the code time.tzname[0] and it returns "Pacific Standard Time".

Comment: Ah. You're checking the local timezone name independent of a `datetime` instance. That works, though it doesn't extrapolate to the scenario where you've got a saved `datetime` from "somewhere" and need to display the associated timezone. It doesn't look like that information is made available for naive `datetime`s, but the cost of importing `time` is trivial (`datetime` imports is during its own import, so `import time` just pulls the cached copy loaded at the same time as `datetime`). Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger just a don't-repeat-yourself practice. Datetime should already have its capability to display time and its info, especially a date should naturally be "aware" of what timezone it's in.

Answer (score 0):

The example for writing your own local timezone `tzinfo` class uses (scroll down one page from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc)) pulls the `tzname` from `time.tzname`, so Python doesn't have a better built-in solution to suggest.

You could copy that example `LocalTimezone` implementation, which would allow the use of the `%Z` format code for `strftime` on an aware `datetime` instance using the `LocalTimezone`, but that's the best you can do with the built-ins. On a naive `datetime` the `tzname` is the empty string, so you *need* an aware `datetime` for this to work.